# What's the difference between the insert methods and why is one faster?

Tags: mysql, database

I have insert 14.485 lines on MySQL like this:

```
INSERT INTO `bairros` (`id`,`cidade_id`,`descricao`) VALUES (1,8891,'VILA PELICIARI');
INSERT INTO `bairros` (`id`,`cidade_id`,`descricao`) VALUES (2,8891,'VILA MARIANA');
...
```

It took around 5 minutes.

I had to insert in another table 16.021 lines, same database, so for test I did this:

```
INSERT INTO `bairros` (`id`,`cidade_id`,`descricao`) VALUES (1,8891,'VILA PELICIARI'),(2,8891,'VILA MARIANA');
...
```

It took just a few seconds.

What is the difference, for the database, between the scripts? And why one is faster than the other?

Comment: Can you post the table's configuration - specifically the `CREATE TABLE` and the list of any indexes the table has? There's a good chance you have an index and too-many inserts one-after-the-other will cause a huge lag due to rebuilding the index after each.

Comment: How are you running the scripts? Is this in MySQL Workbench? From PHP? Or another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that the first script contains 14,485 separate queries, each of which must be committed.

The second is a single query.

Comment: A multi insert is almost always faster than a series of single inserts. A lot of the query execution time boils down to adjusting indexes and waiting for the resulting changes to be committed to disk. This adds up with thousands of queries.